What happens to a woman’s debt?
If a man steals and cannot pay it back, he is sold as an eved Ivri, a Hebrew slave. A women cannot become a slave this way (Mishna Sotah 3:8 - הָאִישׁ נִמְכָּר בִּגְנֵבָתוֹ, וְאֵין הָאִשָּׁה נִמְכֶּרֶת בִּגְנֵבָתָהּ). What happens to her debt? Is the person whom she stole from forced to forgo justice?

Forego sounds permanent. The creditor may just have to wait patiently
